# Vaadin mytheme stylesheet doesn't work on localhost

Tags: vaadin

I am using vaadin designer 8 , when i add some styles in mytheme it appears only with the designer tool not with localhost

mytheme

[image]

Vaadin designer

[image]

localhost

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of hints

1. Recompile the theme ["mvn vaadin:compile-theme"](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-compiling.html) (if I read this right, [Designer does autorecompile on the fly](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/designer/designer-theme.html), which may explain the phenomenom, i.e. via localhost you get old theme)
2. Try shift+refresh on browser, to force re-loading theme. Sometimes browser reads the old theme from its cache.